# Replacing two characters in a string with multiple characters?

Tags: python, regex, bioinformatics

So I'm having trouble with this problem I'm trying to solve. 
Let's say I have a user input a sequence we want to find in a string. But they're allowed to enter 'X' where it will be replaced by 4 characters and search the string. For example if the user enters AXXT, it would search the string for AGCT, AGGT, etc. So this is what I tried to do:

```
y_re = y.replace('X', '[ACGT]')
```

However this does not overlap so I enter AXX and it only gives me AAC. Does anyone know how I can fix this?

Comment: Maybe replace with a mere `.`? `.replace('X', '.')`? Or `[A-Z]`. Could you please provide a test case?

Comment: Please provide a short, **complete** program that demonstrates the error. Please copy-paste your program into your question and include the actual and expected output. See [mcve] for more info.

Comment: *"However this does not overlap so I enter AXX and it only gives me AAC"*: for what string? Please give a clear example and the expected output.

Answer (score 0):

Like the other commenters said, please provide a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example with sample data and expected output.

But I think I understand what you're trying to accomplish. Say, you have the sequence `ACATGT` and the user enters `AXXT`, then you want to find both the overlapping subsequences `ACAT` and `ATGT`. The way to do this using regular expressions is by using [positive lookahead](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html): `(?=...)`.

```py
import re
sequence = 'ACATGT'
user_input = 'AXXT'

pattern = user_input.replace('X', '[ACGT]')
pattern = '(?=({}))'.format(pattern )

m = re.findall(pattern, sequence)
print(m)
```

Comment: I understood the question differently, for `'AXXT'` I think they want something like `['A', [('A', 'A'), ('A', 'C'), ('A', 'T'), ('A', 'G'), ('C', 'A'), ('C', 'C'), ('C', 'T'), ('C', 'G'), ('T', 'A'), ('T', 'C'), ('T', 'T'), ('T', 'G'), ('G', 'A'), ('G', 'C'), ('G', 'T'), ('G', 'G')], 'T']`